Matching Terrestrial LiDAR with Bathymetric Data
We have aerial LiDAR data of an island at low tide, and bathymetric data taken with a fish finder around the island at high tide (with about 1m of error).
Is it possible to combine these datasets? Both can be imported into ArcGIS Pro. If so, how do you match up data at low tide with data at high tide?

Can you show a small example of the two datasets and what you expect the resulting combined dataset to be?
